# Vary based on cookie without producing duplicate cache entries

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm working on a multi-tenant platform where our customers can create online stores. A store might might be selling products in multiple currencies, like EUR and USD at the same time.

Since the prices of the products displayed differ based on the currency, I would like to have pages cached for both eur and usd.

The initial part of getting it to work was rather easy, but I encountered an undesired side effect.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.cookie) {
        cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
        // If the user has a `currency` cookie, set it as a header
        set req.http.x-currency = cookie.get("currency");
    }
    ...
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.x-currency);
}
```

My backend recognizes uses this header, or its absence, in order to render the proper output and then Varnish stores the result. If the request does not have this header, the server sends a `Set-Cookie` header, which will tell the browser to create a cookie with the default currency of the store.

My problem stems from the fact that, in advance, I don't have a way of knowing the default currency of a store ( EUR or USD in our case ), because the owner can add/remove them dynamically.

So, on the first request to the `/homepage` endpoint, the user will not have a `currency` cookie, so its value will be '', and this will be used in the `hash_data` method.

The server recognizes that the client did not have a currency cookie, so it set a `Set-Cookie` header, and when the page hits the browser, the client will have the cookie.

Currently, we have a cache entry for `/homepage` with no `currency` cookie.

The customer hits refresh and the request reaches Varnish.

This time, there is a `currency` cookie, which is used in the `hash_data` function, but it produces a different key, so it hits the backend again, but the output will be exactly the same ( obviously, Varnish does not know that ).

The `/homepage` url has two associated cache entries with it, which both have the same content.

Is there an alternative approach I can take to work around this, or a fix of some sort?

My initial train of thought was:

Go inside of the `vcl_backend_response` subroutine and inspect the request. If the request is missing a cookie, then the `beresp` object will contain the default currency of the store in its `Set-Header`. And I can use that to create 2 different cache keys, which point to the same cache entry - `/homepage + ''` for empty cookie and `/homepage + 'EUR'`.

That's not technically possible, but its an illustration of something which seems to be fixing my problem.

I have not provided a 100% of my vcl configuration for simplicity, but I have used the default vcls as templates to create a customized configuration for `vcl_recv` and `vcl_backend_response`. I know that cookies mean Personalized content and I shouldn't cache that, but the personalization in this case does not work uniquely for this user, so I made an exception.

Edit

[www.mystore.com/en/](http://www.mystore.com/en/) - default currency is USD

```
sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.url !~ "^/(contact|sitemap)") {
        hash_data(req.http.x-currency);
    }
}
```

We have nothing in the cache at the moment

1. User visits the `homepage` for the first time, he has no cookies whatsoever
2. Varnish generates a hash based on `http.x-currency`, which is empty. The result is a miss.
3. Varnish hits the backend, the backend sees the lack of the `x-currency` header, so it sets a Set-Cookie header, which sets the cookie to USD
4. Varnish receives the response, caches it, and sends it back to the client
5. The same user hits a refresh on the same page
6. Varnish generates a hash based on `http.x-currency`, which is now USD ( it was empty last time ), which results in a cache miss, again
7. Varnish goes to the backend, the backend returns the exact same response, because no `x-currency` or `x-currency` = USD means the same for the backend
8. Varnish receives the response, caches it and returns it to the client

The homepage route is now completely cached. No matter if somebody visits with `currency=USD` cookie, or without one, he receives a cached response. However, there are two entries in the cache register, one for an empty `currency` cookie, and one with `currency=USD` cookie, and both of these have the same result.

The problem stems from the fact that, when a request arrives and it doesn't have a `currency` cookie, I don't have a predictable way of figuring out its value without the help of the backend.

It appears to me as though I would just have to live with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you only want to create cache variations for pages that contain different currencies. Based on your information, I'm assuming that the homepage doesn't differ in terms of content and doesn't need the variation.

### URL matching

You can match certain URL patterns that don't need the variations and conditionally perform the variation.

Here's an example:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.url !~ "^/(homepage|contact|sitemap)") {
        hash_data(req.http.x-currency);
    }
}
```

This is an oversimplified example, but I hope you understand that variations can be done conditionally. Either using inclusion or exclusion patterns.

### Sending a Vary header

You can also manage the conditional variation aspect in your application by sending the following `Vary` response header for pages that need to be varied per currency:

```
Vary: x-currency
```

By doing this, you can manage variations from within your application and not depend on `hash_data()` in `sub vcl_hash`.

Keep in mind that the `x-currency` request header needs to be send to the application. That's not really a problem because you have set this header in `vcl_recv`.

> It is important to strip off this part of the `Vary` header in `vcl_deliver` because the client has no awareness of this request header.

### The duplicate key for the homepage problem

In your (updated) question above, as well as in the comments below, you talk about the hypothetical `/homepage` object being cached multiple times based on the `x-currency` header.

This shouldn't really be a problem for you. I noticed that you understand how hashing in Varnish works.

The 2 solutions I mentioned above (URL matching & Vary) explain how to **conditionally** extend the hash. The term *conditionally* is very important here.

If the `/homepage` route produces exactly the same about regardless of the `x-currency` value, it means that `x-currency` shouldn't be part of the hash. This also means that the *URL* and *host header* will form the basis of the hash.

By not adding `x-currency` in `hash_data()` or as part of the `Vary` header, there will be only one version for `/homepage`.

You indicated that `Vary: x-currency` is your preferred solution. I would advise you to only set it for pages that have a different output per currency.

I'm under the impression your problem will be solved by conditionally varying on the currency.

### What about the Set-Cookie header?

Another important remark is about pages that return a `Set-Cookie` header if the currency is not set.

Varnish's standard behavior will result in a so-called *Hit-For-Miss*.

This means that the object is not stored in cache, because you don't want to cache the `Set-Cookie` header for everyone.

For the next 2 minutes, all requests to that resource will bypass the cache, unless the next response becomes cacheable.

In your case the 2nd request to `/homepage` will become cacheable, because the response will no longer contain a `Set-Cookie`.

The result in terms of hit rate is that the first request for every user will be a cache miss because of the `Set-Cookie`.

Please keep this in mind.

Personally I wouldn't be worried about this, but if you do, you can actually strip off `beresp.http.Set-Cookie` to make the page cacheable and set the cookie yourself in `vcl_deliver`.

Of course you'll need to have access to the logic that decides on *EUR* versus *USD* to correctly set the cookie value.

Comment: Sorry, its a bit confusing. I added a more detailed example of the issue in the op. Thank you for these hints, I'm already using some of them.

My best solution for the moment is to not use a custom `vcl_hash` logic, but to rely solely on the `Vary: X-Currency` header. I send that back from my backend, conditionally, only if the shop has more than one currency, which eliminates this issue for shops with one currency, but it still remains if they have two or more.

Comment: Do you think that I can perhaps make use of the vmod for variables and use a global variable for this? The way I think it could work is, in step 3 in the example, the backend response would have an `X-Currency` header, so I can set a global variable, like `var.global_set(req.http.host, beresp.http.X-Curency);`. Then, in `vcl_recv`, I would check for a cookie, if its missing, I will try to find the global variable based on the request host.

Comment: I have updated my response with 2 extra sections. It contains information on how to only have a single variation for select pages and how the set-cookie header impacts your hit rate.